# Filter by field's content contains string

Tags: go, rethinkdb

I've some object :

```
{
    "name":  "universite paris sorbonne" ,
    "id":  "548272c9-6615-4e93-aa15-9af0a830c9a2"
}
{
    "name":  "universite paris dauphine" ,
    "id":  "943234f3-6615-4e93-aa15-9af0a830c9a2"
}
{
    "name":  "universite sorbonne nouvelle" ,
    "id":  "24f477f3-6615-4e93-aa15-9af0a830c9a2"
}
```

How can i do if i would like select each object which contain `paris dau` in their name ?

I've tried with that, but it doesn't work.

```
    curs, _ = r.Table("places").
    Filter(func(customer r.Term) interface{}{
        return customer.Field('name').Downcase().Contains(func (custo r.Term) interface{}{
            return custo.Match(".\\*" + strings.ToLower('paris dau') + ".\\*")
        })
```

any suggest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified your problem a bit by dumping the data into a map and then did a simple regexp match which works well.

package main

```
import (
  "fmt"
  "regexp"
)


func main() {
  data := map[string]string{
    "548272c9-6615-4e93-aa15-9af0a830c9a2": "universite paris sorbonne",
    "943234f3-6615-4e93-aa15-9af0a830c9a2": "universite paris dauphine",
    "24f477f3-6615-4e93-aa15-9af0a830c9a2": "universite sorbonne nouvelle",
  }

  var matches = make([]string, 0)
  for _, value := range data {
    matched, err := regexp.MatchString(".*paris dau.*", value)
    if err == nil && matched {
      matches = append(matches, value)
    }
  }

  fmt.Printf("Matches: %v\n", matches)
}
```